# How do I move box to the right corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, tailwind-css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
        <title>PM</title>
        <style>
          .margin-left{
               margin-left: 10px;
          }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div id='pm-header' class="margin-left my-3 shadow shadow-gray-50 border-cyan-100 border-solid border-2 overflow-hidden"></div>
            <div id="box" class="margin-left box border-2 border-solid border-gray-500"></div>
            <div id="friends" class="flex-1 border-2 border-solid border-gray-500"></div>
            <input class='mx-3' type="text" id="snd">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function resize(){
            var win_h = $(window).height();
            $('#pm-header').height(win_h - 500);
            var htmlhd = $('#pm-header').height();
            var nh = win_h - htmlhd - 100;
            $('#box').height(nh);
            $("#box").width($(window).width() - 260);
            $("#pm-header").width($(window).width() - 260);
            $("#snd").width($('#box').width());
            $("#friends").width($(window).width() - $('#pm-header').width() - 50)
            $("#friends").height($("#box").height() + $('#pm-header').height())
        }
        $(window).on('resize', function(){resize()});
        resize();

    </script>
</html>
```

im using tailwindcss im trying to move #friends to the right corner and fill that space and i dont know how

im using tailwindcss im trying to move #friends to the right corner and fill that space and i dont know how
like this but on right
[how i want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yCoD.jpg)

Comment: Hey @Michael, can you add some more details here?  I took your code and ran it in jsFiddle, and it is 3 empty white divs with a text input at the bottom, and doesn't look much like your provided screenshot.  Are you trying to build a two-column layout, with pm-header, box, and the input on the left, and friends on the right?  Which of the two "right corners" are you trying to move to?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case, based on your `how i want it`  image , i am giving my possible solutions

1. Use fractionally width
   [image]

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="pm-header" class="margin-left my-3 overflow-hidden border-2 border-solid border-cyan-100 shadow shadow-gray-50">Header</div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div id="box" class="box w-2/6 border-2 border-solid border-gray-500">Box</div>
    <div id="friends" class="flex-1 border-2 border-solid border-gray-500">Friends</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Use `flex-1`

[image]

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="pm-header" class="margin-left my-3 overflow-hidden border-2 border-solid border-cyan-100 shadow shadow-gray-50">Header</div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div id="box" class="box border-2 border-solid border-gray-500">Box</div>
    <div id="friends" class="flex-1 border-2 border-solid border-gray-500">Friends</div>
  </div>
</div>
```